# jQuery ajaxStart

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my code, but I'm not getting an alert message, even though I can see the $.ajax call is working correctly.

```
(function($)
 {
    $('.debug').ajaxStart(function() { alert('ajaxStart'); });
 }
)(jQuery);
```

And of course, in the html, I have:

```
<div class="debug">
     <h3>debug info:</h3>
</div>
```

Maybe it's because I use:

```
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that was it.  I changed it to:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
});
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in code ;)

```
(function($)
{ 
    $('.debug').ajaxStart(function()
    {
        alert('ajaxStart');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

You closed the first bracket after anonymous function, but you had to do that after (jQuery).

For example:

**(** function($){ body }(jQuery) **)**;